# Recursive model in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, algorithm

I needed to do an algorithm in the modeler and wanted to try (and also because I couldn't see any other solution) to make it recursive.

Unfortunately, now every time I try to just open the model to modify, QGIS closes immediately.

Although I still can generate a python script with it, I'd like to get my model back to correct it.

I had a conditional branch that was supposed to be my stop for the algorithm, but I don't know if it works.

So my questions :

- Is it possible to do a recursive model in QGIS?
- Can I get my model back?

Here is the python code generated from it

```py
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : Creation de séquence
Group : 
With QGIS : 33402
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
import processing


class CreationDeSquence(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('lignes', 'Lignes', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine], defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(10, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Branche conditionnelle
        alg_params = {
        }
        outputs['BrancheConditionnelle'] = processing.run('native:condition', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Mettre 0 au séquence 0
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'sequence',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 1,  # Entier (32bit)
            'FORMULA': 'if("start"=0,0,"sequence")',
            'INPUT': parameters['lignes'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Mettre0AuSquence0'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # calcul dernière séquence
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'last_seq',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 1,  # Entier (32bit)
            'FORMULA': 'maximum("sequence")',
            'INPUT': outputs['Mettre0AuSquence0']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['CalculDernireSquence'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extraire les séquences non analysées
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD': 'sequence',
            'INPUT': outputs['CalculDernireSquence']['OUTPUT'],
            'OPERATOR': 8,  # est null
            'VALUE': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtraireLesSquencesNonAnalyses'] = processing.run('native:extractbyattribute', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extraire dernière séquence
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': '"sequence"="last_seq"',
            'INPUT': outputs['CalculDernireSquence']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtraireDernireSquence'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(5)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extraire toutes les séquence précédente
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': '"sequence" is not NULL',
            'INPUT': outputs['CalculDernireSquence']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtraireToutesLesSquencePrcdente'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(6)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Prochaine séquence
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtraireLesSquencesNonAnalyses']['OUTPUT'],
            'INTERSECT': outputs['ExtraireDernireSquence']['OUTPUT'],
            'PREDICATE': [4],  # touche
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ProchaineSquence'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(7)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # indiquer la nouvelle séquence
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'sequence',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 1,  # Entier (32bit)
            'FORMULA': '"last_seq"+1',
            'INPUT': outputs['ProchaineSquence']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['IndiquerLaNouvelleSquence'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(8)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # prochain reste
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': 'get_feature(  @Prochaine_séquence_OUTPUT  ,\'ID\',"ID") IS NULL',
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtraireLesSquencesNonAnalyses']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ProchainReste'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(9)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Fusionner les couches
        alg_params = {
            'DELETE': False,
            'INPUT': [outputs['ProchainReste']['OUTPUT'],outputs['IndiquerLaNouvelleSquence']['OUTPUT'],outputs['ExtraireToutesLesSquencePrcdente']['OUTPUT']],
            'MATCH': True,
            'SRCINFO': False,
            'MERGED': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['FusionnerLesCouches'] = processing.run('sagang:mergevectorlayers', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Creation de séquence'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Creation de séquence'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return CreationDeSquence()
```

Comment: Better to post your code to avoid your post getting closed for not meeting GISSE standards.

Comment: @GBG I would post my code but I cannot open it. Maybe I can post the python script output of it

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that this code runs fine in a non-QGIS related Python interpreter (until the recursive limit is met) but it throws an error in a QGIS Python Console on v3.28.7.

```
def print_hello():
    print('hello world')
    print_hello()

print_hello()
```

Here is the error message I get in QGIS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.7\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.7\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 178, in __call__
return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.7\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 106, in _maybe_compile
raise err1
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.7\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 93, in _maybe_compile
code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.7\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 143, in __call__
codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, True)
  File "<input>", line 4
    print_hello()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The code you show isn't working for me either, but I did manage to make a recursive script out of the one I posted. The issue is just that I can't make a stop condition to work or even a watchdog.